# How can I put a space in between the data and the button

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website like Neal dot fun, but I'm calling mine Hello World and I'm trying to figure out how to make a space between my button and my text coming from data. Right now, it doesn't look good with there being no space in between. I would like for the data to be in the middle of the page, if possible using HTML, but if there are other coding languages that you would recommend for formatting, then please say so.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {
  text-decoration: 2px solid powderblue;
  margin: 100px;
  text-align: top;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Whats Next?</h1>

<a href="Hello World Website.html" target="_blank">
    <button style="background-color: blue; color: white;">Back To Home</button>
    
</a>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: middle;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

{



<script>
     


    
    var countDownDate = new Date("Nov 18, 2024 6:00:00").getTime();
    var countDownDate = new Date("Apr 2, 2024 6:00:00").getTime();

    
    
    var x = setInterval(function() {
    
      
      var now = new Date().getTime();
        
    
      var distance = countDownDate - now;
        
      
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        
    
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "Days " + hours + "Hours "
      + minutes + "Min " + seconds + "Sec ";
        
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "NOW";
      }
    }, 1000);
    </script>

}


</body>
</html>
```

I did the span tag and I just don't know where I would put it, because everywhere I put it it just ends up breaking the code or not doing anything.

Comment: The `text-align` values in your CSS [are invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).  A useful tool for finding issues like this is your browser's development/debugging tools, in which you can select an element in the DOM explorer and examine the styles being applied to it.

Comment: It's not just the CSS, the HTML is very invalid, the `body` and `head` seem to be mixed together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use css flexbox for that. You can just wrap your button and the p#demo into a div and give the div `display: flex`. You then assign the respective `justify's/align-items` to the div or the child objects.

And you will have to update your html code, you messed up sth. with your head and body. I would further advise you to separate your HTML, CSS and JS instead of putting it all into the same file.

As you asked for an example, I pasted your code into chatGPT and let it correct it:

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Nov 18, 2024 6:00:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " Days " + hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Min " + seconds + " Sec ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "NOW";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.button-container {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.date-container {
  text-align: right;
}

p {
  text-align: middle;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.button-style {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>

  <h1>Whats Next?</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="button-container">
      <a href="Hello World Website.html" target="_blank">
        <button class="button-style">Back To Home</button>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="date-container">
      <p id="demo"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you show me where it would go like an example